# Axios + reactJS+ passportJS login redirect not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, passport.js

I'm trying to implement user authentication for the first time, I can't get the redirect to work after a successful login.

Function in react:

```js
const login = () => {
    Axios({
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        email: loginEmail,
        username: loginEmail,
        password: loginPassword,
      },
      withCredentials: true,
      url: "http://localhost:5000/login",
    }).then((res) => console.log(res));
};
```

Backend user controller:

```js
exports.login = (req, res) => {
    const { email, name, username, password } = req.body;
    const user = new User({ email, name, username });
    req.login(user, (err) => {
        if (err) return next(e);

        console.log("LOGGED IN")
        res.redirect('/');
    });
};
```

The console messages do print when I enter a valid user/password, but I just can't get the page to redirect after a successful log in.  I've tried using history.push instead of redirecting from the backend, but it would push regardless of whether or not the log in is successful.

```js
    const login = () => {
        Axios({
          method: "POST",
          data: {
            email: loginEmail,
            username: loginEmail,
            password: loginPassword,
          },
          withCredentials: true,
          url: "http://localhost:5000/login",
        }).then(history.push("/"));
    };
```

Does anyone have any insight of why I am unable to redirect from the backend? How can I better approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In backend user controller instead of `res.redirect` send `res.send(// if authentication is completed send true, else send false)`.

Now you can access this message in `then` function.

```
const login = () => {
    Axios({
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        email: loginEmail,
        username: loginEmail,
        password: loginPassword,
      },
      withCredentials: true,
      url: "http://localhost:5000/login",
    }).then((res) => {(res.data===true) && (history.push("/"))});
};
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I ended up using!

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
const login = async () => {
            const res = await Axios({
              method: "POST",
              data: {
                email: loginEmail,
                username: loginEmail,
                password: loginPassword,
              },
              withCredentials: true,
              url: "http://localhost:5000/login",
            });
           // if success
          history.push("/");
        };
```

Comment: Always a good practice to have a try catch with async await.